# Restore daily MYSQL dump to new SQL Server Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, backup, restore

We have a daily backup restore from MYSQL in the form of a .sql file. I want to move that to the SQL Server or to the Azure SQL database.
please suggest the way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a script or use a tool to automate the migration of data from .sql files in MySQL to SQL Server or Azure SQL. This script should be scheduled to run daily after the .sql file is created, ensuring the automation of the data restoration process.